# Android - Lost keystore and tried uploading APK with another package name

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I lost the keystore of my Android app. The app was only published in the Alpha Track for a limited list of testers. No Production Track yet.

I contacted Google about it and they told me to

- unpublish the app, which I did
- change the package name, which I did in the Android manifest

In the Alpha track I still see the previous release with the status of **fully implemented**

After that I did the following

1. Clicked on *Make Release*
2. Clicked on *Upload APK*
3. Uploaded the new APK

**RESULT**: I get the error that I uploaded an APK that has been signed with another certificate than previous APKs.

What am I missing here? Do I need to change the package name somewhere else as well? Or do I also have to change the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName`?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the package name everywhere it is used.

Comment: I believe you have to create a new app listing.

Comment: @squeeish: but can I re-use the same app title for that new app? I unpublished the old app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the way to solve this. For anyone who has the same question, here are the steps that you should follow:

1. Unpublish the app in the Google Play Console
2. In the store listing tab, change the name of your app
3. Create a new app
4. Re-use the same name for that new app by putting it in the store listing form

That's it. Hopefully you don't have too many (or none) users who already downloaded your app. Otherwise you'll have to let them know about the change.